# Datasource not defined in JNDI environement (JBOSS EAP 6)

Tags: jboss, datasource, jndi, jboss-eap-6

I'm trying to run an application using a Datasource on JBOSS EAP 6.4
In the standalone.xml file my data source is well defined. 
When I try a :

```
   Context context = new InitialContext();
   NamingEnumeration<NameClassPair> list = context.list("");
   while (list.hasMore()) 
   {
      String name = list.next().getName();
      System.out.println(name);
   }
```

I only get TransactionManager while I'm expecting as well my data source named in the standalone.xml as jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/OracleDS".

Why my datasource is not defined in the jndi environnement? Am I missing some configuration?

Answer (score 0):

The [`Context.list(Name)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/naming/Context.html#list-javax.naming.Name-) does not include subcontexts. In other words you cannot iterate through all the registered names using `context.list("")`. If you want to list the data sources you'd need to use `context.list("java:jboss/datasources)`.

The reason you only get the `/TransactionManager` is because it's the only one defined under the root namespace.